# Parallelism with .NET 4.0 in a desktop sqlite single thread application?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing

Where do you see operation scenarios for parallelism/multi-threading/PLINQ etc for a single threaded WPF desktop app with sqlite?

I would like to know wether I could tune my application somehow and even when it is just for the learning effect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what your app is doing. If you at all are doing data processing of some kind you should look into whether data can be split up into independent units and thus be able to process these in parallel.

LOB apps process data even if it just means "fetch Customers from database and present them in a list". Perhaps you could do the fetching asynchronously while doing some "loader" animation in the view. Though simple, it is still parallelism and still a learning challenge to get it working.

That said, trying to parallelize stuff that already runs well on a single core is overkill. Perhaps you should look for a different project to try out parallelism.

Comment: its just a LOB app. Get data from sqlite and show it in a nice wpf mvvm application.

Comment: Well Peter my data comes that fast (therefore I chose sqlite) that I do not need any progress/loading bar. 90K inserts in 0.5 seconds :P seriously now , it seems there is no use for async stuff when the data comes immediately right?

Comment: @Lisa - I would agree, trying to parallelize stuff that already runs well on a single core is overkill. Perhaps you should look for a different project to try out parallelism.

Comment: please put the last comment in the solution so I can mark it! :)